# Efficient approach to do search using SearchBar,SearchDisplayController and UITableView

Tags: iphone, core-data, uisearchbar

I want to do postcode search using SearchBar,SearchDisplayController and UITableView. I am thinking of doing it using CoreData,  but still I want to know if anyone has some efficient idea to do the same.

And database have 15000 row, so is it advisable to port sqlite file into application and use core data API to fetch the results.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

The most commonly used persistent storage for CoreData is implemented on top of sqlite3, so they have fairly similiar performance characteristics interms of raw fetch peformance, etc. It has a lot of code to handle faulting in objects in the background without blocking, evicting them under memory pressure and transparently refaulting them as necessary, etc. In the strictest sense if you are going to spend an immense amount of time (think months to years) optimizing for a specific case then a direct sqlite3 implementation can beat CoreData, but the vast majority of the time CoreData will beat any simple sqlite3 based implementations.